# Air resistance force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, projectile, drag

How do I find the air resistance force and the maximum air resistance force when all I'm given is the mass, terminal velocity, and I know it's falling in quite air? I found a formula online but it requires the drag, density and cross-sectional area which I do not have.

Comment: The *maximum* air resistance is possible to find from this data, but the *instantaneous* air resistance requires more info e.g. about the velocity or the air and object proporties as you mention yourself.

Comment: I'm guessing you found the formule here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_%28physics%29.

Just define a constant $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}\rho C_d A$ which consists of all of your unknowns. This way you need to determine $\alpha$ in the formula $F_D=\alpha v^2$.

Comment: At terminal velocity, the force of gravity is equal to the drag force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general,
$$F_R=bv^2$$
where $F_R$ is the resistive force, $b$ is a constant and $v$ is the object's velocity. The net force on the object also depends on gravity:
$$\sum F = bv^2 -mg = ma$$
When $v$ is the terminal velocity, $a=0$. So
$$bv_t^2=mg \to v_t^2 = \frac{mg}{b} \to v_t = \sqrt{\frac{mg}{b}}$$
That's how terminal velocity is calculated.

In this case, $v_t$ and $m$ are given (and, of course, $g$). So we can solve for $b$:
$$b=\frac{mg}{v_t^2}$$
And so the resistive force at a given speed is
$$F_R=\frac{mg v^2}{v_t^2}$$
The trouble is that $F_R$ is a function of $v$, and it appears that $v$ is not given (in the case where $v \neq v_t$). If you're given the velocity (as well as the other factors), you can solve for $F_R$. If not, you can't solve the equation.

As for the case where $v = v_t$ . . . see Steeven's answer.

---

Here's the math for why $a=0$ when $v=v_t$:
$$=\frac{mgv^2}{v_t^2} \to F_t=\frac{mg v_t^2}{v_t^2}=mg=F_g$$
$$\sum F=F_R-F_g=mg-mg=0$$
So $a=0$.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I find the air resistance force and **the maximum air resistance force**

For the last part (emphasized in bold face), here's a hint: If you fall at the terminal velocity, then you don't speed up anymore. No acceleration. The air resistance has rosen to a value that gives an equilibrium between the forces up and down. Newton's first law can help you from here...

For the first part of the question, you need more info about the air or the velocity (see the other answers).

Answer (score -1):

If you do not have the cross sectional area together with the mass and the ballistic coefficient of the falling body you can not tell the air resisting force. A feather falls slower than a hammer in air. The force is given by

$$F_{(t)} = \frac{cW\cdot A\cdot \rho\cdot v_{(t)}^2}{2}$$

where $\rho$ is the density of the air, $v_{(t)}$ the instant velocity of the moving body and $cW$ the ballistic coefficient.

The instant velocity for any given time is calculated differentially, see [Link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/162219/what-is-the-force-required-to-move-a-raindrop/162229#162229)

Comment: This is not entirely true. If you know all other forces acting (and you know the acceleration), then you can find the air resistance force without knowing this formula.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, but the question was >> *all Im given is the mass, terminal velocity, and I know it's falling in quite air?* << so your assumption to know all other forces acting is not justified.

Comment: The question lacks information in either case. But regardsless, your statement `If you do not have the [...] you can not tell the air resisting force` is what I reacted to, since this is not entirely true.